# Converting int into binary and returning sum of its digits

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to convert an integer into its binary value and then print out the sum of its digits. 
my code is as follows:

```
number = 30                    # declare int
binary_number = "{0:b}".format(number)        # convert into binary
# print(binary_number) gives output of 11110 

print(sum(int(item) for item in binary_number ))     # print out the sum of 
digits
# works and gives gives an output of 4 (1+1+1+1+0)
```

but when I try to phrase the logic in another way it gives an error and I cannot figure why:

```
for item in binary_number:
   print(sum(int(item)))

# output is error:
#Type Error: 'int' object is not iterable
```

thank you in advance for your help!
regards,
Andy

Comment: Maybe you should read [the docs on ``sum()``](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)

Comment: You should just do `print(int(item))`. Why do you need the `sum`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expression

```
int(item) for item in binary_number
```

gives an *interable* which is why `sum(int(item) for item in binary_number)` works.

These lines

```
for item in binary_number:
   print(sum(int(item)))
```

set `item` successively to `"1"` `"1"` `"1"` `"1"` `"0"` and inside the loop your code does `sum(int(item))` which resolves to either `sum(1)` or `sum(0)`. Now do you see why `sum()` doesn't do what you expect? As the error message says, an 'int' object is not iterable. Since you don't have an iterable, you need to do your own summing:

```
total = 0
for item in binary_number:
   total += int(item)
print(total)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation makes perfect sense !

Answer (score 0):

Your rephrasing changed the semantics from

```
print the sum of the elements of a list
```

to

```
for the elements in this list print the sum of each single item.
```

Answer (score 0):

Mapping the binary number to integers and summing them will give the desired result.

```
sum(map(int,"{0:b}".format(number)))
```